# override viewWillDisappear for all View Controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

is there a way to override viewWillDisappear (or any view controller delegate method for that matter) across ALL of my view controller in my entire app?

To be clear, I would still like to customize each viewWillDisappear method in the view controller's themselves, but basically I'd like to add a line of code to each view controller's viewWillDisappear method without having to do it manually (it's a big project).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just make a base ViewController that only overrides the functions you want and then have every viewcontroller in your project inherit from that rather than UIViewController. Also to make your life easier add the #import of your base view controller to your .pch file.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Especially the .pch tip. That and a find and replace turned a would-be tedious task into a quick and tidy solution.

Comment: Is there some way to override method for both UITableViewController and UIViewController?

Comment: A TableViewController is just a subclassed ViewController. I think you have two options. 1. Create your own ViewController which subclasses your base view controller and implements the <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> or 2. Just make your UITableViewController and make it a ViewController which extends the base viewcontroller and has a tableview as its view. I guess it depends on how many tableview controllers you have.